# Return templet string from the selected country code

Tags: swift

I would like to get the pre-define temple name based on the country selection. Here I'm trying some code, but unable to get that from code. How do I get back messages based on the country code input?

```
enum Descriptor: String, CaseIterable, CustomStringConvertible {
    case fr = "FR"
    case jp = "JP"
    
    var description: String {
        get {
            return self.rawValue
        }
    }

    var mesage : String {
        let templet = "Welcome to "
        switch  self {
        case .fr:
            return templet + "France"
        case .jp:
            return templet + "Japan"
        }
    }
}

extension Descriptor {
    static func hasCountry(code: String) -> String? {
        return Descriptor.allCases
            .map({$0.rawValue})
            .first(where: {$0.description == code})
    }
}


let x = Descriptor.hasCountry(code: "JP")
print(x)

// Expected output is like
// Welcome to Japan
// or
// Welcome to France
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
extension Descriptor {
  static func hasCountry(code: String) -> String? {
    return Descriptor.allCases
                     .first(where: {$0.description == code})?
                     .mesage
  }
}
```

You have a tiny bit of mistake in your extension.

So when you do .map({$0.rawValue}), you actually transform all your enum cases to a strings array ["FR", "JP"].

What you actually want to be doing is find your first enum case, and call .mesage on that one.

Comment: Thank you very much @Vlad Rusu I got my mistake

Comment: Awesome! Would you please mark this as the correct answer then? Thanks